# How to pass data from PHP to python

Tags: php, python

How to pass data from PHP to Python?
This is my code.
PHP:

```
$data = 'hello';
$result = shell_exec('/home/pi/Python.py' .$data);
```

Python:

```
result = sys.argv[1]
print(result)
```

But when run python code it show error:

`"IndexError: list index out of range"`.
 don't know Why?
Is it have other code for pass data from PHP to python?

Comment: Not sure how it works that far, you seem to be executing the command `/home/pi/Python.pyhello`

Comment: add a space between command and arguement

Answer (score 3):

Provide space between command and argument:

try the following snippet

**php** : test.php

```
<?php

$data = 'hello'; 
$output=shell_exec("python test.py "  .$data);

echo $output;


?>
```

**python** : test.py

```
import sys
result = sys.argv[1]
print(result+" by python!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add space after script name

```
$data = 'hello';
$result = shell_exec('/home/pi/Python.py ' .$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a machine-learning web application using PHP and here is how I send my data from PHP to Python file. So, I have created a simple PHP and Python file and sent data accordingly.

test.php

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("py test.py 1 2 3 ");`
?>
```

py: is the location of your python.exe. You can either use py or python depending on your operating system.
test.py: is the location of your python file. if both PHP and Python are in the same folder, you can write the name of the Python file here.
1 2 3: is the array of data you want to send to the Python file.

test.py

```
import sys
num_1 = sys.argv[1]
num_2 = sys.argv[2]
num_3 = sys.argv[3]
total = int(num_1)+int(num_2)+int(num_3)
print(total)
```

Hope it helps